# Camel ftp get file from ftp location on demand

Tags: camera, jbossfuse, integration-patterns

Hi I have a scenario where I get notified through a soap service call to pick file from an remote ftp location.The ftp server details would be same but the folder name and file will be sent dynamically,
How can i implement it using apache camel.?
Any suggestions or thoughts might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use **headers** for that. So, you will load your dynamic information into headers and use them in the ftp component with **toD**.

So you can have something like the following

```
<toD uri="sftp:username:password@ftp.server.com/${header.CamelFolder}?fileName=${header.CamelDownloadFile}"/>
```

But since you want to get from an FTP in the middle of the route you can try **Content Enricher EIP**

```
<route>
  <from uri="..."/>
  <!-- set your dynamic values as headers -->
  <setHeader headerName="CamelFolder">
     <simple>...</simple>
  </setHeader>
  <setHeader headerName="CamelDownloadFile">
     <simple>...</simple>
  </setHeader>

  <pollEnrich>
    <simple>sftp:username:password@ftp.server.com/${header.CamelFolder}?fileName=${header.CamelDownloadFile}</simple>
  </pollEnrich>
  ...
</route>
```

Comment: Hi Themis,I need to a file from FTP location on demand and not sending file to a FTP location.

Comment: Hi, you are right i got confused. But if you use from with dynamic information at headers? Did you try it?

Comment: Hi iam not sure how to retrieve the the file in the middle of the route.Using from uri will always keep polling to the ftp location and to/toD uri is used to send to remote ftp.Is there any EIP pattern that can be used?

Comment: I think you need Content enricher Eip. See http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html section Using dynamic uris